# What to do on Compile Error: Else without if

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, compilation

Please Help. The VBA returns as compile error: else without if. can you point out my error?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
If (KeyAscii >= 47 And KeyAscii <= 58) Or KeyAscii = 46 Or KeyAscii = 32 Then KeyAscii = KeyAscii

Else
KeyAscii = 0
MsgBox "Invalid Input"

End Sub
```

Comment: Move the part after `Then` to its own line and add `End If` before the `End Sub`

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much. It's now working. I'm still a newbie don't know anything about this.